# Is it possible to manually execute and transform a Behavior

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

Say I define a real-time thermometer actor thus:

```
case class Temperature(centigrade: Int)

object Thermometer {

    trait Command
    case class Test(replyTo: ActorRef[Temperature]) extends Command

    def apply(): Behavior[Command] = Behaviors.receiveMessage {
        case Test(replyTo) =>
            replyTo ! Temperature(???)      // take a real time measurement
            Behaviors.same
    }
}
```

And an actor that reacts to temperature changes as follows:

```
def reactor(thermometer: ActorRef[Thermometer.Command], floor: Int, ceiling: Int): Behavior[Temperature] = {

    def next(context: ActorContext[Temperature]): Behavior[Temperature] = Behaviors.receiveMessage {
        case Temperature(centigrade) =>
            thermometer ! Thermometer.Test(context.self)
            if (centigrade < floor) low(context)
            else if (centigrade > ceiling) high(context)
            else next(context)
    }

    def low(context: ActorContext[Temperature]): Behavior[Temperature] = Behaviors.receiveMessage {
        case Temperature(_) =>
            // Carry out behavior specific to a previous low temperature
            next(context)
    }
    
    def high(context: ActorContext[Temperature]): Behavior[Temperature] = Behaviors.receiveMessage {
        case Temperature(_) =>
            // Carry out behavior specific to a previous high temperature
            next(context)
    }

    Behaviors.setup(next(_))
}
```

I want to add an actor that simulates temperature changes by reading them from a database. I would want to do this in such a way that I do not read the next simulated temperature until I know my reactor has processed the previous one:

```
object SimulatedThermometer {

    trait Command
    case class Simulate(temp: Temperature) extends Command
    case class Ack(reactor: Behavior[Temperature]) extends Command

    def apply(temps: Seq[Int], reactor: Behavior[Temperature]) = {
        
        def iterate(temps: List[Int], reactor: Behavior[Temperature]): Behavior[Command] =
            Behaviors.receive {
                case (ctx, Simulate(temp)) =>
                    // Our reactor should process temperature here
                    val newReactor = reactor(temp) // HOW TO???
                    ctx.self ! Ack(newReactor)
                    Behaviors.same
                case (ctx, Ack(behavior)) => temps match {
                    case h :: t =>
                        // Can now proceed to process next temperature 
                        ctx.self ! Simulate(Temperature(h))
                        iterate(t, behavior)
                    case _ =>
                        Behaviors.stopped
                }
            }

        iterate(temps.toList, reactor)
    }
    
}
```

But is there any way in Akka that I can manually execute this Behavior and transform it to the next Behavior?

Note. I know it would be possible to change my reactor behavior to send a reply when it has processed the message. But this is not necessary for the real-time behavior and the reactor should not have to be aware of whether its acting in real-time or in simulation

Comment: the messages of an actor always get sequentially processed in the same order they get received.

Comment: You can look into the “exactly once” projection mode of akka projection with persistent actors and JDBC. Basically, one persistent actor, which can be your simulator, persists events in a database as a result of receiving commands, then these events get asynchronically picked up and processed by a projection process, which can send them to your reactor, one by one and only send each message to it, after a reply is received acknowledging the processing of the previous one.

Comment: Is the intent to test the temperature-handling logic of the reactor in a synchronous way? It could be much simpler to factor out that to pure functions that you can call from your test.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the intent. And factoring out was the alternative - but wanted to see of there is a way I could directly execute a behavior as this would allow me to stick to a simple actor implementation for my reactor - but seems like this is not an option

Comment: @user79074 doing it inside actors is usually best if you want to maintain some state for the actors performing the task or when you want to do the computation asynchronously or concurrently when it’s CPU intensive or blocking otherwise. In this case, using a pure function sounds like a more natural solution.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a use case for the `BehaviorTestKit`, which would look something like:

```scala
def apply(temps: Seq[Int], reactor: Behavior[Temperature]): Unit = {
  val testkit = BehaviorTestKit(reactor)
  temps.foreach { temp =>
    testkit.run(Temperature(temp))
    // testkit is guaranteed to have fully processed the message
    // assert effects on the testkit

    // example: you can even save behavior (mainly to spawn a new testkit) and time travel (modulo side effects)
    val nextBehavior = testkit.currentBehavior
    ()
  }
}
```